# How to change the alignment of this text?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, align, indentation

My code:

```
Theorem: If $(X,T)$ is $T_{2}$-space and $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ is convergent sequence, then $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ has a unique a limit.
```

How to make the change below so that "Theorem:" is separated on it own?

[image]

Comment: It would be more (La)TeXish to not simply write out "Theorem: ...", but instead `\theorem{...}` - or how it is commonly done: `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\theorem[1]{\begin{list}{Theorem:}{\itemindent-2.125em\leftmargin4.67em}\item#1\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\theorem{If $(X,T)$ is $T_{2}$-space and $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ is convergent sequence, then $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ has a unique a limit.}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the `amsthm` theorem package, you could proceed along the lines shown in the code below. It creates automatic hanging indentation by (a) defining a suitable macro (called `\hangit`) that sets the values of the parameters `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` and (b) arranging for this macro to be executed at the beginning of every `theorem` environment.

If the hanging indentation is needed for just one instance, you could still set the parameters `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` "on the fly," as is also shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\hangit}{%
   \settowidth{\hangindent}{\textbf{Theorem \thetheorem.}\hspace{0.5em}}%
   \hangafter=1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\hangit}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
If $(X,T)$ is $T_{2}$-space and $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ is a 
convergent sequence, then~$\langle{x_n}\rangle$ has a unique a limit.
\end{theorem}

\noindent
\settowidth{\hangindent}{Theorem: }\hangafter=1
Theorem: If $(X,T)$ is $T_{2}$-space and $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ is a convergent sequence, then $\langle{x_n}\rangle$ has a unique a limit.
\end{document}
```